# What's the upper-bound for an array index/subscript in GNU bc?

Tags: array, size, bc

I've found that there is an upper-bound on your subscripts/indices in an array in GNU [bc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_(programming_language)). Running interactively and asking to let `arr[100000000]=42` returns an error:

```
 Runtime error (func=(main), adr=17): Array arr subscript out of bounds.
```

This array size limit isn't listed among bc's [limits](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html#SEC22), and it doesn't appear the "variable names" limit of 32767 affects this since bc accepts `arr[100000]=42` without complaint. What is the exact bound on bc's array subscripts/indices? Is there a way to change this bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the `bc` limits:

```
$ echo 'limits' | bc
BC_BASE_MAX     = 2147483647
BC_DIM_MAX      = 16777215
BC_SCALE_MAX    = 2147483647
BC_STRING_MAX   = 2147483647
MAX Exponent    = 9223372036854775807
Number of vars  = 32767
```

And into `man bc (1p)` we see:

> Arrays are singly dimensioned and  can  contain  up to {BC_DIM_MAX}
> elements. Indexing shall begin at zero so an array is indexed from 0
> to {BC_DIM_MAX}−1.

Looking into [1.07.1](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bc/) it is defined into file `const.h`.

```
/* Definitions for arrays. */

#define BC_DIM_MAX   16777215     /* this should be NODE_SIZE^NODE_DEPTH-1 */

#define   NODE_SIZE        64     /* Must be a power of 2. */
#define   NODE_MASK      0x3f     /* Must be NODE_SIZE-1. */
#define   NODE_SHIFT        6     /* Number of 1 bits in NODE_MASK. */
#define   NODE_DEPTH        4
```

Comment: I have no idea if you could compile a bc with a custom array subscript limit for your linux, you would have to research for it or ask the authors. But for your installed bc, it is not configurable.

Answer (score 0):

Through trial-and-error, the upper-bound is 2²⁴ = 16,777,216. Still not sure *why* this is the upper-bound or how to change it.

Comment: `bc` (or at least the underlying `dc`) supports any single-char name for an array, so that is another factor of 256, or `2 ^ 8`. I'm guessing it allocates space for `2 ^ 32` total array entries, and hopes most of those will not be mapped into RAM. All the used values can be arbitrary-precision too, of course.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, the GNU version of bc isn't built on dc, though, and it seems to support multi-character array names.

Comment: @ilkkachu  Good point. I used SunOS for most of my time. I much prefer raw `dc`over `bc`: I tend to use awk to throw arbitrary-precision stuff into `dc` -- my awk Pi script using Chudnovsky is fun.